# Can "which" and its antecedent be used together in a sentence for reading clarity?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, relative-clauses, construction, relative-pronouns

Unfortunately I could not find an authentic example of the rare construct I have in mind, but I am just as sure as I am typing this question that I have read so many sentences from older prose where the relative pronoun "which" and the noun it refers to are *both* there. In this case, it sounded almost as though "which" were used as "such."

Which + its antecedent.

The following example is mine, not taken from any authentic author; but it attempts accurately to emulate many sentences I have read:

> Yet a certain problem still persists in this society, which problem has been
>   handed down from one generation to another.

Could it be that a writer is allowed to do so to avoid the syntactic ambiguity of whether "which" refers back to "society" or "problem"? Now of course the rest of the sentence may clarify for the reader what the antecedent for "which" is (without having to mention it); meaning that ". . . handed down from generation to another" gives the impression that the antecedent is indeed "problem." But still, could the combination of "which" followed by its antecedent "problem" be used to give the reader a more fluid and smooth reading experience?

Comment: I think I have seen this construct but modern usage would more likely be: "Yet a certain problem still persists in this society, a problem which has been handed down from one generation to another."

Comment: It may, for all I know, improve reading clarity, but like all archaic formulations, it's distracting. This is another variety of pied-piping, which variety repeats the noun antecedent, turning _which_ into a modifier instead of pronoun. It's cumbersome, and it's consciously archaic -- or will be read that way. If this is a legal document, however, this does not apply. Laws and decisions have used this for a long time, and legal language is **sposta** sound archaic, the harder to understand it.

Comment: @John Lawler: I Couldn't help my curiosity. Is a there a reason why you emboldened 'sposta' besides that it's spoken? Also, did you type "which variety" on purpose, as a creatively contextualized example of the phenomenon? Or was it an a coincidence?

Comment: @asef: To contrast it with **not sposta**, of course. And, yes, I often try to demonstrate the grammatical points I'm discussing. The more examples the better, especially if they arrive subliminally. Plus, if you know what you're doing, language is great fun to mess with.

Comment: @John Lawler: Many thanks for efforts. I am particularly thankful that you've referred me to pied-piping phenomenon.

Comment: You're welcome; it's an interesting topic, [one that comes up here pretty often](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+pied+piping), though this phenomenon should probly be called piping-pied.

Answer (score 1):

The [Wikipedia article on English determiners](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_determiners) contains:

> **Relative determiners**:
>
> which (quite formal and archaic, as in He acquired two dogs and three
>   cats, which animals were then...);
>
> also
>
> whichever and whatever (which are of the type that form clauses with
>   no antecedent: I'll take whatever money they've got).